# How should I handle when I have the same route in both angular and express?

Tags: express, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular and node. I have same route http://localhost:3000/posts/58b66083eda0a8200858b736 in both angular and node. So when I click on the link First it is redirected to node route. There I'm doing some checking then I have to redirect to angular route. So if there is any way please let me know.

Comment: It's bad idea to have the same routes for api and navigation. Use /api/posts/<GUID> in node instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It generally considered best practice to namespace your express routes.  So rather than /post/:id you would have /api/post/:id.  That way you avoid naming collisions and you can treat your app as a seperate client and server.

Comment: I will do that but if I want to do it my way, can I do that or is it not allowed?

Comment: You can do anything you want but you will get undesired behavior from name collisions in the routes.

Comment: So how can I redirect from node route to angular route?